# Error regarding 'IEnumerable<>' does not contain a definition for '' ....'' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<>' could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor, ienumerable

I'm facing the mentioned error for Username only, but not for password? I am confused as to what I could be doing wrong.

In index.cshtml:

```
  <input id = "Username" asp-for="Username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
  <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="Password" asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
  <span toggle="Password" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
  <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

And in LoginCredentials:

```
    public class LoginCredentials
    {
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        
        [Key]
        public string Username { get; set; }    

    }
```

The error itself states

> IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Username' and no extension method 'Username' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You are missing asp-for="Username", inside the first input tag.

Comment: Where do you get that error exactly?

Comment: @NikolaDevelops I am so sorry, that was an error on my part while uploading! This still gives the error- the error is right on asp-for="Username" and asp-validation-for="Username", underlining username

Comment: Post the code where you get the error. Everything is fine in this (except that you have a closing div out of nowhere after the span validation for username).

Comment: What is the model for that view?